# Connect MS Project 2010 to MS Project Server 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I am trying to get a tutorial or step by step instructions on how to connect MS Project 2010 to MS Project Server 2010.

I have installed Server 2008 R2 (64 bit), Sharepoint 2010, and Project 2010 on my server and created a new site using the project 2010 template.

I am now trying to connect my stand alone Project 2010 to that site for updates and such.

I tried the File->Info->Manage accounts option and it comes up with "Could not retrieve server initialization data."

I cannot find a step by step tutorial to set it up or to trouble shoot the error message.

Any hints or good resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use the http:///pwa as your account URL
Also, make sure you add your users under Server Settings --> Manage Users in the PWA site, you can't just add them via SITE PERMISSIONS.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one important step: creating a PWA (project web application).
After you install sharepoint and project server you must build a pwa and then enter this address to project. Here is a very good and complete guide for creating and setiing up PWA:
[Create a PWA site (Project Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426866%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Deploy Project Server 2010 to a test environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426873%28v=office.14%29.aspx)